# How do I insert a newline within a long formula using OpenOffice.org Math?

Tags: openoffice

I've the following formula:

```
(x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1)(x^7+x+1)
= x^13+x^11+x^9+x^8+x^7+
x^7+x^5+x^3+x^3+x^2+x+
x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1
= x^13+x^11+x^9+x^8+2x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+2x^3+2x^2+2x+1
```

Putting this in OpenOffice.org Math causes every line be concatenated, which I want to avoid. I've already tried putting `newline` between the lines, but it adds a strange question mark in the formula. Using matrices did not work for me either.

I want to achieve a nicely formatted formula like this one (taken from [FIPS 197 pdf](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf)):
[image: Nicely formatted formula]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the answer om the [OpenOffice.org forum](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=4396). Rather than inserting `newline`, `{}newline{}` should be used instead.

In my case:

```
(x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1)(x^7+x+1){}newline{}
= x^13+x^11+x^9+x^8+x^7+{}newline{}
x^7+x^5+x^3+x^3+x^2+x+{}newline{}
x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1{}newline{}
= x^13+x^11+x^9+x^8+2x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+2x^2+2x+1
```

To get it nicely aligned to the left, I used:

```
alignl (x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1)(x^7+x+1){}newline
alignl {}= x^13+x^11+x^9+x^8+x^7+{}newline
alignl {}""phantom{=}x^7+x^5+x^3+x^3+x^2+x+{}newline
alignl {}""phantom{=}x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1{}newline
alignl {}= x^13+x^11+x^9+x^8+2x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+2x^2+2x+1
```

`alignl` causes the text to be **align**ed to the **l**eft; `""phantom{=}` inserts an hidden `=`, which adds the extra whitespace before the line. (found at [FAQ: How do I align my equations at the equality sign](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Formula/How_do_I_align_my_equations_at_the_equality_sign%3F))

If you're curious how the formula looks like:

[image: Result in OOo Math]

Answer (score 0):

this one works for me:

```
size 20 { } F_y=0 drarrow  newline  +N-w_y=0  { }
```

Edit:

the previous line of code has trouble with "size" or "bold"  commands, as well as the "=" symbol -they don't work. I think a better way to deal with this problem is to write the formula line by line using {} at the end of each line, like this:

```
size 20 { F_y=0 drarrow {} }
```